# FaceBook FQL Query Not Working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

We have used the v2.0 graph API & FQL(FaceBook Query Language) for getting the FaceBook details in our project. But recently the result is empty.

I have checked the developer.facebook.com and i found one solution that is Login Review process. We need to get the FB details means we need to get the pre approval from FB.(user_photos, user_videos) It'll work perfectly or not ?

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/04/28/april-30-migration/

**Sample Code :**

args = "SELECT uid,name FROM user WHERE uid = me()"
file = urllib2.urlopen("https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?" + urllib.urlencode(args), timeout=3)

Please give some suggestion to fix this problem.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/api-v1-deprecation

Advance Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_1_deprecations

> The FQL and REST APIs are no longer available in v2.1: Previously announced with v2.0, apps must migrate to versioned Graph API calls starting with v2.1.

You're querying the REST API which is deprecated, as cited. Use https://graph.facebook.com/fql instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We have used the v2.0 in our project. Is it possible to use the FQL ? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/api-v1-deprecation pls check this link

Comment: We have used only v2.0, the FQL will support or not ?

Comment: You're querying the REST API which is deprecated, as cited. Use https://graph.facebook.com/fql instead. And, by the way, it depends on the date your app was created which Graph API version you can use. Furthermore, it's not clear to me why you have to use FQL at all.